# Adjust UILabel on the content size with autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I am trying to understand the basic of dynamic layout using the intrinsic content size. As attached in the image, i have two UILabel's in horizontal which will be my default layout. How do make the layout constraints so that

- If the content size of either of two labels are greater than the other , it should be arranged in vertical stack
- Also if either of two labels content size is greater than one line,how do we make the text grow satisfying the vertical arrangement

[image: AutoLayout]

Comment: "If the content size of either of two labels are greater than the other , it should be arranged in vertical stack". In the first case(image), second label content size is clearly greater than the first label's, but you want them horizontally. Could you clarify?

Comment: @PuneetSharma Consider the 2th section with two labels "Testing on autolayout" & "Autolayout is fun and i am crazy !!!:)". By default the uilabels are arranged horizontally Since the second label text has more character than first label , the second label should come the first   one

Comment: That means the two labels should be in horizontal stack until they are greater than a fixed width.

Comment: @PuneetSharma yes that's right

Answer (score 1):

You can add two labels to stackView and if the sum of **intrinsicContentSize** of and check with the `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` minus the margins of left and right of stackView.

```
if (label1.intrinsicContentSize.width + label2.intrinsicContentSize.width) > (UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 48/* 48 is the left and right margins*/) {
     stackView.axis = .vertical
}else {
     stackView.axis = .horizontal
}
```

Remember to set the numberOfLines of labels to 0.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my answer using constraints

Comment: @Nassif Great Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the condition using four constraint outlets.

- Consider L1 & L2 as firstLabel & secondLabel respectively placed horizonally
- Add leading space from L1 to superview
- Add top space from L1 to superview
- Add height for L1 >= someValue
- Add trailing space for L1 with value >= someValue and a priority of 999
- Add leading space from L2 to leading of L1 , give a low priority and make a nsconstraint outlet connection
- Add horizontal space from L2 to L1 , give a low priority and make a nsconstraint outlet connection
- Add align top from L2 to L1 , give a low priority and make a nsconstraint outlet connection
- Add vertical space from L2 to L1 , give a low priority and make a nsconstraint outlet connection
- Add height for L2 >= someValue
- Add trailing space for L2 with value >= someValue and a priority of 999

  ```
      let firstWidth : CGFloat = (firstLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width)!
  let secondWidth : CGFloat = (secondLabel?.intrinsicContentSize.width)!

  if (firstWidth + secondWidth) <= self.view.frame.size.width - 45.0 {

       secondLabelLeadingConstraintTofirstLabelLeading?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)
       secondLabelSpacingConstraintTofirstLabel?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
       secondLabelTopConstraintTofirstLabelTop?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
       secondLabelTopConstraintTofirstLabelBottom?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)

  }
  else {

      secondLabelLeadingConstraintTofirstLabelLeading?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
      secondLabelSpacingConstraintTofirstLabel?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)
      secondLabelTopConstraintTofirstLabelTop?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 250)
      secondLabelTopConstraintTofirstLabelBottom?.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)

  }
  ```